# DSolve for ODEs with terms like $ y^2(t) $

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

*Mathematica* does not give me any solution for the ODEs as follows:

```
eqns = {t x'[t] == a x[t] t + b y[t]^(1/3), y'[t] t == b x[t], x[t0] == 1, y[t0] == 1};
sol = DSolve[eqns, {x, y}, t]
```

However, if I change it into

```
eqns = {t x'[t] == a x[t] t + b y[t], y'[t] t == b x[t], x[t0] == 1, y[t0] == 1};
sol = DSolve[eqns, {x, y}, t]
```

in which I simply change `y[t]^(1/3)` into `y[t]`, MMA gives me a solution.

This is really strange.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Don't look down upon `^(1/3)`. It is not a small potato. Because its existence determines the equations are nonlinear.

Comment: Moreover, `y[t]^(1/3)` causes the underlying vector field to be _not_ Lipschitz continuous which might result in nonuniqueness (and even nonexistence?) of solutions for certain starting values.

Comment: Do you know an analytic solution, even in a special case (e.g. `a = b = t0 = 1`)?

Comment: Is your `t0` equal `0`?

Comment: `DSolve` provides a solution for  `a -> 0`, if initial conditions are omitted.